# onChange handler doesn't work in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular 6 project.
I have this dropdown in my template which render the dropdown correctly:

```
<select id="companydropdown" onChange="getcompanyid(this)">
<option *ngFor="let company of filteredCompanies" value={{company.companyName}} 
id={{company.id}}>
{{company.companyName}}
</option>
</select>
```

and in my component

```
getcompanyid(s)
{
var id = console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].id);
alert(id);
}
```

But the method never fires

Comment: Please review the documentation first on template event syntax https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding-event as you’d see it would (change)=“getcompany($event)”

Comment: Voting to close as typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

//This may help you.

```
<select id="id" name="id" required  #id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="company.id" class="form-control" (change)="getcompanyid(company.id)" >
                                <option [ngValue]="null">Select company Name</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let dept of filteredCompanies" [value]="dept.id">
                                    {{dept.companyName}}
                                </option>
                            </select>



//in component
getcompanyid(id:any)
{
alert(id);
//do some stuff with this id.
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the (change) event should pass the dept id. How would I do that?

Comment: dept id is similar to company.id, both are same.

Comment: company.id is not in scope so the code won't compile.
filteredCompanies: User[]; and Companies:User[] are declared in the component

Comment: What I'm looking for is generic code that shows how to pass the id of selected option when the option changes.

Comment: above example is angular select and it is perfect work, because of two way binding properties of angular. if you are using jquery then use like                               $('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    ....
});

Comment: I told you company.id is not in scope so my angular app does not compile...so i cannot test your solution

Comment: Can you please update your code to work without company.id. There is no field company.id in scope so it won't compile